# Request.Querystring i Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

If I have these to lines of classic asp, I get an error.

```
KId = (Request.Querystring("KID") - 1000000) / 1531

KNr = ""&Request.Querystring("Knr")
```

If I comment out one of them, there is no error.

As I remember, I don't need to put anything at the end of each code to end a line, am I right?

Comment: What error you get exactly, and on which of the lines?

Comment: I get only error 500. The server settings is set to not showing the errors.
But maybe I think it is another error that is giving med the 500 page. 
Maybe the database is not returning anything.

Comment: So you really should set the server to show full error. It's essential part of developing or debugging a web application, and once you're done you can turn it off again for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put anything at the end of the line.

I think you need to cast the querystring to an int before you can do math on it:

```
KId = (cInt(Request.Querystring("KID")) - 1000000) / 1531

KNr = ""&Request.Querystring("Knr")
```

I don't have a classic asp test bed to check for sure.